# What is the correct way of installing firebase-tools (a npm package) in NixOS/Nix?

Tags: npm, package-managers, firebase-tools, nix, nixos

I am watching this [Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-javascript-and-firebase/) on Firebase. The course is a bit dated, initially made maybe 6 years ago.

At some point the author indicates how to use firebase CLI, hence he indicates the command:

```bash
~/projects/chatlive]$ npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I added `sudo` to avoid permission problems:

```bash
~/projects/chatlive]$ sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Unfortunately, this error message is retrieved:

```bash
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /nix/store/nm7vm9d7xbvibazz7kl7xkqgjddqgiby-nodejs-14.18.3/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /nix/store/nm7vm9d7xbvibazz7kl7xkqgjddqgiby-nodejs-14.18.3/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, access '/nix/store/nm7vm9d7xbvibazz7kl7xkqgjddqgiby-nodejs-14.18.3/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-28T15_33_55_544Z-debug.log
```

I am using [NixOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NixOS) and this is my [config file.](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-nixos-config/blob/main/configuration.nix) Since the error message mentions the `nix/store` I thought it could be related.

Usually, I install things in NixOS changing my `configuration.nix` and doing `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`. But I thought it would **not** be necessary to do it considering npm was managing the installation.

Searching on Nix packages, I can see `firebase-tools`: [link](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.05&show=nodePackages.firebase-tools&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=firebase-tools). Now, it seems that tweaking the config file is the way...

In situations like this, what is the best practice?

Should I force trying to install via npm (how?)? Should I go for a new generation of NixOS and a full system rebuild just because of this package?

Is there another possible path? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to play around with `firebase-tools` in a development environment, create a `shell.nix` file in your working directory and add the following lines:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:

pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgs.nodePackages.firebase-tools ];
}
```

Then run `nix-shell` to start a shell with `firebase-tools` included. This is considered **best practice** for local development environments, see https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell .

If you want to try out packages not in nixpkgs repo you should use `npm` and install a package locally (without `-g` ). See https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Node.js#Using_npm_install_-g_fails.